# When and where was the first "official" fan organized Lego Convention held?

Tags: history, afol

I just attended BrickCon 2013 here in Seattle (I wore my new StackExchange T-shirt). When and where was the first "official" fan organized Lego Convention held?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [What is BrickCon?](http://brickcon.org/about/what-is-brickcon/) page, BrickCon claims to be the "longest running fan-based LEGO® convention". Its first edition took place in 2002.

Note that there are events which are older ([LEGOworld in the Netherlands](http://www.legoworld.nl/english) for example which I believe started in 2001), so I suppose BrickCon's claim is specific for conventions, and not exhibitions - although I doubt the line between both is very clear to start with (While LEGOworld is definitely directed to the public, there are fan-only happenings in the evenings)

Comment: I remember attending LEGO exhibitions at the Meier and Frank department store in Portland, OR in the 1970s. These were exhibits of large-scale models similar to those at LEGOland. I do not recall if the exhibitions were officially LEGO-sponsored or not.

Comment: +1. Although BrickCon is the longest consecutively running yearly Lego Con in North America, I'm not sure that it was the first fan organized Lego convention.

Comment: There were also a fair amount of official fan events before everybody started using the internet. A bit harder to tell, there.